# how to set layout background image in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to set VerticalFieldManager background image. here is my code hope it would help you to find problem.

my problem is 
1)  background image is appear but not get full height of the image.

```
VerticalFieldManager verFM = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH );
    Bitmap bt = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("top_bar@2x.png");
    BitmapField btm = new BitmapField(bt);
    btm.getPreferredHeight();
    verFM.add(btm);


    VerticalFieldManager VFM = new VerticalFieldManager( USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
    VFM.setMargin(5, 5, 10, 40);
    VFM.setPadding(5, 5, 60, 10);
    System.out.println();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("registration_form_bg@2x.png");
    Background bgg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmap,Background.POSITION_X_LEFT, Background.POSITION_Y_TOP,Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT);

    VFM.setBackground(bgg);
    verFM.add(VFM);
    add(verFM);
```

Comment: show the image ?. Because we don't know your image height. why you using Background ?. You can directly add bitmapfield to your VFM .

Comment: when you say "not get full height of the image", are you talking about top_bar@2x.png or registration_form_bg@2x.png?